# Парсим xml на php c использованием регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, xml

Вообщем есть файлик на html в нём через форму грузим xml файл примерно такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Statements>
    <Statement acc="40702810800170000370" beginDate="2018-07-01" bic="044525503" creditSum="0.00" creditSumNat="0.00" datePLast="2018-06-29" debetSum="0.00" debetSumNat="0.00" endDate="2018-07-31" enterBal="2193951.34" enterBalNat="0.00" lastMovetDate="2018-06-29" orgName="Р“Р‹Р“Р‹Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“Р‡Р“В Р“В©Р“вЂљР“В®Р“В°Р“В¤Р“В±&quot;" outBal="2193951.34" outBalNat="0.00" rateIn="1.0000" rateOut="1.0000" stmtDateTime="2018-07-17T13:19:49">
    <Docs/>
</Statement>
<Statement acc="40702810800170000370" beginDate="2018-07-01" bic="044525503" creditSum="39165.01" creditSumNat="39165.01" datePLast="2018-06-29" debetSum="79937.00" debetSumNat="79937.00" endDate="2018-07-31" enterBal="2193951.34" enterBalNat="0.00" lastMovetDate="2018-06-29" orgName="Р“Р‹Р“Р‹Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“Р‡Р“В Р“В©Р“вЂљР“В®Р“В°Р“В¤Р“В±&quot;" outBal="2153179.35" outBalNat="0.00" rateIn="1.0000" rateOut="1.0000" stmtDateTime="2018-07-17T13:19:49">
    <Docs>
        <TransInfo carryDate="2018-07-02T00:00:00" chargeOffDate="2018-07-02" dc="1" docCurr="810" docDate="2018-07-02" docNum="13071" docSum="30.00" payeeAcc="70601810300002740201" payeeBankBic="044525503" payeeBankCorrAcc="30101810545250000503" payeeBankName="Р“Р‚Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“РЉР“РЏ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„&quot;" payeeINN="7750005482" payeeName="Р“Р‚Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“РЉР“РЏ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„&quot;" payerAcc="40702810800170000370" payerBankBic="044525503" payerBankCorrAcc="30101810545250000503" payerBankName="Р“Р‚Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“РЉР“РЏ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„&quot;" payerINN="7724838375" payerName="Р“Р‹Р“РЋР“в„–Р“ТђР“В±Р“Р†Р“СћР“В® Р“В± Р“В®Р“Р€Р“В°Р“В Р“В­Р“РЃР“В·Р“ТђР“В­Р“В­Р“В®Р“В© Р“В®Р“Р†Р“СћР“ТђР“Р†Р“В±Р“Р†Р“СћР“ТђР“В­Р“В­Р“В®Р“В±Р“Р†Р“СР“С• &quot;Р“вЂР“Р‡Р“В Р“В©Р“вЂљР“В®Р“В°Р“В¤Р“В±&quot;" paymentOrder="5" paytKind="0" purpose="Р“Р‰Р“В®Р“В¬Р“РЃР“В±Р“В±Р“РЃР“С— Р“В§Р“В  Р“В°Р“В Р“В±Р“В·Р“ТђР“Р†Р“В­Р“В»Р“Тђ Р“В®Р“Р‡Р“ТђР“В°Р“В Р“В¶Р“РЃР“РЃ Р“В±Р“В®Р“Р€Р“В«Р“В Р“В±Р“В­Р“В® Р“Р†Р“В Р“В°Р“РЃР“Т‘Р“В Р“В¬ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„Р“В ." receiptDate="2018-07-02" uip=" " valueDate="2018-07-02" writeOffDate="2018-07-02T00:00:00">
            <DepartmentalInfo docDate="2018-07-02" docNo="13071"/>
            <DiffDoc/>
        </TransInfo>
        <TransInfo carryDate="2018-07-02T00:00:00" chargeOffDate="2018-07-02" dc="1" docCurr="810" docDate="2018-07-02" docNum="13092" docSum="30.00" payeeAcc="70601810300002740201" payeeBankBic="044525503" payeeBankCorrAcc="30101810545250000503" payeeBankName="Р“Р‚Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“РЉР“РЏ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„&quot;" payeeINN="7750005482" payeeName="Р“Р‚Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“РЉР“РЏ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„&quot;" payerAcc="40702810800170000370" payerBankBic="044525503" payerBankCorrAcc="30101810545250000503" payerBankName="Р“Р‚Р“Р‹ &quot;Р“вЂР“РЉР“РЏ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„&quot;" payerINN="7724838375" payerName="Р“Р‹Р“РЋР“в„–Р“ТђР“В±Р“Р†Р“СћР“В® Р“В± Р“В®Р“Р€Р“В°Р“В Р“В­Р“РЃР“В·Р“ТђР“В­Р“В­Р“В®Р“В© Р“В®Р“Р†Р“СћР“ТђР“Р†Р“В±Р“Р†Р“СћР“ТђР“В­Р“В­Р“В®Р“В±Р“Р†Р“СР“С• &quot;Р“вЂР“Р‡Р“В Р“В©Р“вЂљР“В®Р“В°Р“В¤Р“В±&quot;" paymentOrder="5" paytKind="0" purpose="Р“Р‰Р“В®Р“В¬Р“РЃР“В±Р“В±Р“РЃР“С— Р“В§Р“В  Р“В°Р“В Р“В±Р“В·Р“ТђР“Р†Р“В­Р“В»Р“Тђ Р“В®Р“Р‡Р“ТђР“В°Р“В Р“В¶Р“РЃР“РЃ Р“В±Р“В®Р“Р€Р“В«Р“В Р“В±Р“В­Р“В® Р“Р†Р“В Р“В°Р“РЃР“Т‘Р“В Р“В¬ Р“РѓР“В Р“В­Р“Р„Р“В ." receiptDate="2018-07-02" uip=" " valueDate="2018-07-02" writeOffDate="2018-07-02T00:00:00">
            <DepartmentalInfo docDate="2018-07-02" docNo="13092"/>
            <DiffDoc/>
        </TransInfo>
        ...
    </Docs>
</Statement>
</Statements>
```

Тут небольшие проблемы с кодировкой, но это не важно.
Вообщем надо собрать в массив вот эти атрибуты:`chargeOffDate`, `payeeName` и `purpose` при этом надо обязательно использовать регулярку, я без регулярки могу это получить, а вот с регуляркой не особо выходит, помогите.

Comment: В каком виде вам нужен массив, можете показать пример?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie ну что-то типа:
`Array(
    [0] = Array(
        [Statement_acc] = [
            [0] = Array(
                [chargeOffDate] = '';
                [payeeName] = '';
                [purpose] = '';
            )
        ]
    )
)`
Что-то вроде это-го

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'/chargeOffDate="(?<ch>[^"]+).+?payeeName="(?<pa>[^"]+).+?purpose="(?<pu>[^"]+)/m'
```

Как по мне, чтобы не запутаться, здесь можно использовать регулярное выражение с именованными группами, в данном случае я обозначу `chargeOffDate - ch`, `payeeName - pa`, `purpose - pu`. Поехали :)

В переменной `$string` будет храниться сам XML изначально

```
preg_match_all(
    '/chargeOffDate="(?<ch>[^"]+).+?payeeName="(?<pa>[^"]+).+?purpose="(?<pu>[^"]+)/m',
    $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

Далее проходим циклом, и полученные данные из `$matches` записываем в новый массив

```
foreach ($matches as $k => $v)
{
    $new['Statement_acc'][$k] = [
        'chargeOffDate' => $v['ch'] ?? $v['ch'],
        'payeeName' => $v['pa'] ?? $v['pa'],
        'purpose' => $v['pu'] ?? $v['pu']
    ];
}

print_r($new);
```

Получаем нужный результат:

```
Array
(
    [Statement_acc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [chargeOffDate] => 2018-07-02
                    [payeeName] => Nick1
                    [purpose] => Content1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [chargeOffDate] => 2018-07-02
                    [payeeName] => Nick2
                    [purpose] => Content2
                )
        )
)
```

Демо этой реализации можете посмотреть вот [здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1216d644843bf2b0584acda71ff507de988d4e3f).

Comment: `m` у вас для чего? Вы же не используете в шаблоне якорные метасимволы.

Answer (score 1):

Если не обращать внимание на сам факт разбора xml c помощью регулярок, то можно предложить следующим вариант действий. Сначала выбрать регуляркой имена атрибутов и соответствующих значений. Потом разбить их в группы по 3, а затем соединить в массивы.

```
preg_match_all('/(chargeOffDate|payeeName|purpose)="(.*?)"/', $xml, $matches);

$keys   = array_chunk($matches[1],3);
$values = array_chunk($matches[2],3);

$result = array_map('array_combine', $keys, $values);
print_r($result);
```